# Orderer capability V1_3 is required but not supported: But, I'm using 1.3.0 images

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I set up channel that has following compatibility, (set in `configtx.yaml`)

```
Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V1_3: true
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V1_3: true
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V1_3: true
```

and started the orderer with well generated genesis block file. I also specified orderer image version:

```
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.3.0
```

and it gives error

```
2018-11-28 01:36:41.191 UTC [orderer/commmon/multichannel] checkResourcesOrPanic -> PANI 005 [channel testchainid] config requires unsupported orderer capabilities: Orderer capability V1_3 is required but not supported: Orderer capability V
1_3 is required but not supported
panic: [channel testchainid] config requires unsupported orderer capabilities: Orderer capability V1_3 is required but not supported: Orderer capability V1_3 is required but not supported

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc4201d1600, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:229 +0x4f4
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc42016a270, 0x4, 0xdfecd3, 0xf, 0xc4203a1888, 0x2, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0xf6
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(0xc42016a270, 0xdfecd3, 0xf, 0xc4203a1888, 0x2, 0x2)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159 +0x79
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panicf(0xc42016a278, 0xdfecd3, 0xf, 0xc4203a1888, 0x2, 0x2)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:74 +0x60
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel.checkResourcesOrPanic(0xeabe80, 0xc4202c8ac0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel/registrar.go:58 +0x14d
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel.(*Registrar).newLedgerResources(0xc42027c480, 0xc42016cc80, 0xc42016cc80)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel/registrar.go:259 +0x304
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel.NewRegistrar(0xea36a0, 0xc42011c2e0, 0xc42015b710, 0xe9b060, 0x15a78b0, 0xc42016a318, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel/registrar.go:142 +0x312
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.initializeMultichannelRegistrar(0xc4201e0580, 0xe9b060, 0x15a78b0, 0xc42016a318, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:258 +0x250
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Start(0xdf7a5a, 0x5, 0xc4201e0580)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:96 +0x226
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Main()
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:75 +0x1d6
main.main()
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/main.go:15 +0x20
```

What should I do to fix this error? What I want to achieve is setting up a network that's only compatible with Hyperledger Fabric 1.3 nodes.

---

I tried with orderer capability `V1_2` and it gives same (except version string) error. Does this mean capability version independent to Hyperledger Fabric version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HLF 1.2 & 1.3, the orderer still only supports V1_1 capabilities. So, your `configtx.yaml` should be:

```
Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V1_3: true
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V1_1: true
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V1_3: true
```